# Erro de ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException ao tentar armazenar valores no vetor

Tags: java, array, classes

Estou tentando,através do Scanner, pegar os valores digitados pelo usuário,armazenar em um vetor e por fim,realizar a média dos valores digitados,no caso a média das nota de um aluno. Porém,estou tendo essa exceção de array fora do index, e não estou conseguindo identificar o que está errado no código.Abaixo minha classe contendo meus métodos e minha classe contendo meu main,respectivamente.

Classe dos métodos

```
package classeexercicios;

public class MediaAluno {

    double vetorNotas [] = new double[5];
    double media;
    double total = 0;
    int i;

    double receberNotas() {
        if(vetorNotas[i] >= 0 || vetorNotas[i] <= 100) {
            for(i = 0;i < vetorNotas.length;i++) {
                total = total + vetorNotas[i];
            if(vetorNotas[i] < 0 || vetorNotas[i] > 100) {
                System.out.println("Insira uma nota valida entre o intervalo de 0 a 10");
            }
        }
    }
        return i;
    }
    double calcularMedia() {
        total = total + vetorNotas[i];
        return media = (total / vetorNotas.length);

    }

}
```

Classe contendo o Main

```
package classeexercicios;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MediaAlunoTeste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        MediaAluno nota = new MediaAluno();
        for(int i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
        System.out.print("Insira a nota do aluno:");
            nota.vetorNotas[i] = teclado.nextDouble();

            nota.receberNotas();
        }

        nota.calcularMedia();

        System.out.println();


        teclado.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Melhor seria separar a classe da execução, você misturou um pouco as coisas.

você está tentando somar o total com o vetorNotas na posicão 5?

```
double calcularMedia() {
                        //aqui
        total = total + vetorNotas[i];
                              // esse vetorNotas.length é apenas um 5 poderia utilizar o índice
        return media = (total / vetorNotas.length);

    }
```

Se já tinha o total era só dividir pela quantidade de vezes passadas no índice.

```
// seu pacote

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MediaAlunosNotasArray {

    double vetorNotas [] = new double[5];
    double total = 0;
    int i;
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    double receberNotas() {
            for(i = 0; i < vetorNotas.length;i++) {
                System.out.println("Insira uma nota valida entre o intervalo de 0 a 10");
                vetorNotas[i] = Double.parseDouble(entrada.next());
                if(vetorNotas[i] > 0 && vetorNotas[i] <= 100) {
                    total += vetorNotas[i];
                } else {
                    i--;
                    vetorNotas[i] = vetorNotas[i-1];
                }

            }
        return total;
    }
    void calcularMedia() {
        System.out.println("media é " + total / i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MediaAlunosNotasArray alunos = new MediaAlunosNotasArray();
        alunos.receberNotas();
        alunos.calcularMedia();
    }
}
```

seu problema ficou um pouco vago na descrição, caso minha resposta não for válida posso editar.

Comment: Entendi,arrumei aqui e funcionou. Muito obrigado